# scipy curve_fit returning initial parameter estimates

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to use scipy curve_fit to fit a gaussian function to my data, for which there are MANY helpful examples on the web, and I have tried to get several to work, but to no avail.  I wrote a simple script using made-up data to diagnose the problem.  In short, curve_fit is not doing any fitting, the function is just returning the initial parameter values, no matter how close they are to the real numbers.  Here is the code for the simple script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from scipy import optimize

##Fit
def Fit( datax, datay ):    
    # define your function:
    def f(x, *p): 
        p = m, b     
        return m*numpy.asarray(x) + b
    m = 0.4
    b = 2.4
    p_init = [m, b]
    Initial_model = f(datax, [m, b])    
    plt.plot(datax, Initial_model, label='Initial Model')
    plt.title("Initial Model")
#    plt.title('Initial Model')
#    plt.show()
   # fit! (given that data is an array with the data to fit)
    print optimize.curve_fit(f, datax, datay, p_init)
    coeff, var_matrix = optimize.curve_fit(f, datax, datay, p_init)
    global fit
    fit = f(datax, *coeff)
    plt.plot(datax, fit, 'r-')
    plt.show()
    print 'Fitted slope 1 = ', coeff[0]
    print 'Fitted intercept 1 = ', coeff[1]
    return fit

##Plot
def Plot( datax, datay, fit ):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.plot(datax, datay, 'b*')
    l = ax.plot( datax, fit, 'r-', linewidth=2)
    ax.set_xlabel('Rate')
    ax.set_ylabel('Return')
    ax.set_title("Test")
    ax.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)
    ax.grid(True)
    plt.show()

##data
datax = numpy.array([7.02, 20.06, 13.78, 16.92, 10.17], dtype=numpy.float64)
datay = numpy.array([5.14, 10.66, 8.44, 9.64, 6.79], dtype=numpy.float64)

##analyze
Fit( datax, datay )
Plot( datax, datay, fit )

Out:
(array([ 0.4,  2.4]), inf)
Fitted slope 1 =  0.4
Fitted intercept 1 =  2.4
```

Things I have tried:
-using leastsq directly: same problem
-reinstalling scipy: no change

I am using Anaconda on Windows 7.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What happend is you add noise to your data and change the initial guess so it is no longer the same as the actual parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `f()` is peculiar and does not do what you want.  You are assigning `m` and `b` to `p` thus overwriting whatever was passed in.  This is why the parameters never appear to change, because they don't change!

There is no need to define `f()` in a peculiar way, just define it the way that makes sense listing the parameters as you normally would.  For your simple case of fitting a line we can use

```
def f(x, m, b) :
    return m*x + b
```

The only other change needed is

```
Initial_model = f(datax, *p_init)
```

and your code will run.